# open browser window (or other window) to very big width and height

Tags: windows, browser

B"H

When I'm openning a web browser like chrome, I can resize the width of the window to some width, but not more then a certain maximum.
I want to open it to size like 3000x3000, more then my screen resolution.
Is it possible?

Thanks
Elchanan

Answer (score 0):

You can use zoom for this purpose. For Chrome and Opera right click on the page, go to "Inspect", then press "Toogle Device Toolbar" (Ctrl+Shift+M). In the toolbar you can specify a big resolution like 3000x3000 and it will adjust zoom according to your screen resolution.

Comment: B"H. It works, but I need another thing. I need the posibility to copy the screen of the site to Image, with the full resolution (3000x3000). is that posible?

Comment: yes, this can be easily done by javascript library phantom.js (http://phantomjs.org/). If you go to "Screen Capture" section in the documentation, there are ~10 lines of code to do this. Of course, you can use other web scraping library, like scrapy or something.